# How do I set up multiple unique accounts via command line?

Tags: command-line-interface, user-accounts, batch-file, windows-registry

I have to setup and configure about 60 (+ more in the future) windows 7 embedded PC's with the same settings. Each of these PC's will have 12 accounts on them. Each of the accounts will have their own unique settings, desktop, programs, etc. They are industrial machines and will not be hooked up to a server or the internet.

I have written a batch file to set everything up. After using the command line to add a new account, I then do the setup for that account.

The problem I am having is that since no one has ever logged into the just created accounts the registry is not set up for it, and when I copy files, and load registry settings things get messed up. And when you log onto an account it comes up as a temp account that nothing can be saved to.

When I stop the batch file after creating the accounts, Then manually switch to each account (which sets up the registry), then continue the script, everything works great.

How do I log in or force the initial log in set up to run? Is there a way to set up the registry defaults to be different depending on the account logged on to?

This is outside of what I normally do and am basically learning this as I go so please type slow :)

Comment: What you should do is to create a default user profile with all of the settings that you want the users to have. Then when each user logs on for the first time their user profile will be configured accordingly.